# Drupal: How to Figure Out the token for a Specific Field?

Tags: drupal, field, token

I would like to know how to 'construct' tokens. I have read many examples, but somehow I don't understand them. I am new to Drupal and at the moment I am testing how it works. I'm trying to hide the title of a content type I've created and automatically replace it with the content of another field. As far as I know, I have installed and enabled all the relevant modules including CCK and Automatic Entity Label. The only thing I don't know is what token I should use to make it happen. The field I would like to use as the source for the title field is called event (or possibly field_event) and is of type text. I'm visually impaired and either I'm doing something wrong, or the token browser is not too screen reader friendly. Either way, I can't access the list of all tokens to select the token, so I have to enter it manually. If I'm not mistaken, the token should include '[node:body]', right? But is it like '[node:event:body]' or '[field:event:body]' or something else?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Idea might be the devel module https://drupal.org/project/devel . Install it, activate it and visit some page of the node type you want to use the token on, and click on the devel tab and then on the token tab. et voila. or you navigate directly to e.g. yoursite.com/node/29/devel/token .

Hope it helps.